# Swift: Cannot put an array to nil

Tags: arrays, swift, swift2, var

What I want to do is, have an array variable, that is initialized whenever it is called. For this I have used `lazy` keyword when declaring it.
However, I have a clear method, where I want to clear the contents of the array(in **constant amount of time complexity**), for which I am doing nil to the array. This gives me an error: `Cannot assign a value of type NilLiteralConvertible to a value of type [Int]`. How do I resolve it?

```
class Array
{
lazy var elementsInArray = [Int]()

func add(element: Int) {
    elementsInArray.append(element)
}

func clear() {
    elementsInArray = nil
}
}
```

Comment: You do realize, your array isn't an optional so it can't be nil right?

Comment: Also, just use the removeAll() function... it's there for this exact reason (the performance hit to this is absolutely negligible to where in most scenarios it's not worth even thinking about).

Comment: If you are going micro-performance, consider that making the array optional will probably also add overhead for every access to it.

Comment: @TheCodingArt Performance is a big requirement, cannot negotiate on that

Comment: @NikitaP I advise you to run a benchmark test in the XCTest framework the to test the time and performance then. But your problem is you need to just turn the array to an optional array.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So, finally What I did to make it working was:

```
class Array {
    private var _elementsInArray:[Int]?
    var elementsInArray:[Int]? {
        get {
            // If while accessing, this array is nil, initiate it with an empty array
            if _elementsInArray == nil {
                _elementsInArray = [Int]()
            }
            return _elementsInArray
        }
        set {
            _elementsInArray = newValue
        }
    }

    func add(element: Int) {
        elementsInArray?.append(element)
    }

    func clear() {
        elementsInArray = nil
    }
}
```

A Big thanks to @PrajeetShrestha and @Thilo for helping me out.

Comment: use Blakusi's answer instead. by the way define class Array is not the best idea ....

Comment: Overly complex for an issue that can be resolved with either optionals or empty arrays.

Comment: TBH, I am just trying to learn, how this can be done if it is of utmost importance. I agree that using removeAll is the easiest approach to this simple problem.

Answer (score 8):

`elementsInArray = []` works as well as  `elementsInArray.removeAll()`

This is just assigning an empty array to the variable.

Comment: This is the best answer, at all.

Answer (score 3):

There is a method for that:

```
class Array
{
    lazy var elementsInArray = [Int]()

    func add(element: Int) {
        elementsInArray.append(element)
    }

    func clear() {
       elementsInArray.removeAll() //use this.
    }
}
```

Comment: `removeAll()` uses a complexity of `array.capacity` as in the description of the method. I want to achieve removing all elements in complexity 1. Any ideas?

Comment: sorry not sure about how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

To assign any variable `nil` it should be declared as an optional. `Int` is different from optional `Int?`. Similarly `[Int]` array is different from optional `[Int]?`array

```
class Array
{
lazy var elementsInArray:[Int]? = [Int]()

func add(element: Int) {
    elementsInArray!.append(element)
}

func clear() {
    elementsInArray = nil
}
}
```

So you should change it as above to assign nil value to elements in Array.

Comment: Not quite! If we write [Int?] Then the array would allow to add nil value, it is [Int]? Hence the array could be nil itself .

Comment: thank you for this. I was doing `:[Int]?`, although I did not realize I have to put explicit unwrapping `!` with it. Silly me.

Comment: @Thilo will not the `lazy` declaration take care of that, and assign an empty array whenever it is being accessed?

Comment: Thilo is right. So if you assign nil to an array. The array doesn't have any memory allocated to it. So you need to re initialize it .

Comment: @PrajeetShrestha even with `Lazy`? I thought it worked like: `if nil, assign`

Comment: @NikitaP: Good question. How does `lazy` work? Initialize on first access? Or initialize when `nil` (even if it had a value before).

Comment: So lazy just instantiates object when accessed for a first time. Not after it. So it will be nil when we try to add an element after u assign nill value to it.

Comment: ok..good to know. What do you suggest making a getter for this array, and doing it the Objective-C way? Initialize every time it is nil?

Comment: Not sure. Wouldn't it be a overkill?